# maven missing artifact

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have a  maven project which until yesterday was being build normally. Now whenever i try to build using m2e it fails to build because it could not resolve dependencies, but these dependencies are not missing and they are found in my local repository. I know that this question has been asked before but none of the answers solved my problem. I have tried many things:

- deleting the cache.
- closing the project and reopening it.
- doing a clean install of the project.

Yet no result. So is there more systematic procedure to solve this problem?

Edit log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building itunit-workflow 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-converter:jar:5.13 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.279s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 16 18:30:10 GMT+02:00 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project itunit-workflow: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.itunit.itunit:itunit-workflow:ejb:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-converter:jar:5.13, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE: Cannot access central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-converter:jar:5.13 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: try running custom goal `mvn clean install -o` o specifies offline

Comment: you can do it from both the places, for eclipse `run as > maven build...` note 3 dots and then type this goal

Comment: same problem could not resolve dependency

Comment: also run `mvn clean install -e -U` and post the log

Comment: Please check that you use the same maven installation in eclipse preferences.

Comment: @hoaz it the same installation.

Comment: @jigar joshi same error with exception like dependency resolution exception , artifact not found exception etc...

Comment: activiti-bpmn-converter:jar is not there in local cache, try rebuilding project if it is your project, or else check with connectivity with the repository that contains this artifact + also see if that repository is listed to lookup for your pom

Comment: but it is there, and it was being build normally 2 days ago. i believe there's other error

Comment: It could be corrupt inside your repository.  You may need to rebuild repo indexes. Alternatively you may have repo stanzas inside your POM or settings.xml that is messing it up.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the contents of your local artifact repo?

Comment: yes i deleted and replaced them many times

Comment: Which Eclipse and m2e versions are you using?

Comment: the error states: "Cannot access central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode" - so did you enable offline mode somewhere?

Comment: no, i didn't enable offline mode but i am working in a machine without internet(don't wont to use offline) . but i have all the dependency in my local maven repository

Answer (score 19):

This usually happens when changing from one maven configuration to another. In my case, I was switching from direct connection to maven central to using nexus as a mirror.

Deleting `maven-metadata*.xml` and `_*.repositories` inside local `\Users\YourUser\.m2` folder did the trick for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Deleting maven-metadata*.xml and _*.repositories worked for me. Thanks. Another thought is, it is not a bad idea to clean up .m2 folder when we switch one maven configuration to another.

Comment: Just removing `_*.repositories` did the trick for me already, didn't need to remove `maven-metadata*.xml`

Comment: BTW @bob-cac, this should be the accepted answer, IMHO.

Comment: That was it. I have profiles set up for different maven repos, so when I was running in offline mode `-o`, I still had to run with the right repo profile on.

Answer (score 15):

In IntelliJ:
-go to File
-settings
-on search box top left type 'maven'.
-click on maven option
-see if work offline box is checked. if yes then uncheck it

In Eclipse:
-click on the small dropdown arrow on the green Run icon.
-click on run configurations and select you maven build config
-see if 'offline' box is checked. if yes then uncheck it

If you did this and still getting same issue then I would go with @Faliorn solution

Comment: Indeed, disabled "Work offline" option and it worked.
Why I had this option enabled in the first place, that's a question...
Thanks

Comment: The solution worked for me. "Work offline" option was checked it then worked when I unchecked, reimported all the maven to the project and I restarted IntelliJ

Comment: Amazing!! This option must be set by default....

Answer (score 2):

I faced with this problem when tried make install with Intellij IDEA Maven plugin. But when I made install with local Maven installation, problem was gone.
If you have same problem try to install new Maven and run `mvn install`