# Intellij IDEA - issue with Maven dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, maven-3

Getting below Error:

Failed to execute goal on project app-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.api:app-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact com.sony.spe.rainbow:common:jar:1.0 has not been downloaded from it before.

Sample pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test.api</groupId>
<artifactId>app-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: ״ Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode״ - you're not connected to the internet...

Comment: Please note that I've connected with internet, still I'm getting same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven missing artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615585/maven-missing-artifact)

Comment: Deleted maven-metadata*.xml and _*.repositories inside local \Users\YourUser\.m2 folder but sill getting same error, please assist

Answer (score 19):

In IntelliJ Idea there's an option:

> In the Maven tool window, click The Toggle Offline Mode button.
>
> This will append the --offline option to all Maven commands that
> IntelliJ IDEA runs. It will also report any items that cannot be found
> in the local repository.

Or in Maven settings.xml:

```
<offline>false</offline>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was that I accidentally activate the offline mode of Maven in IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Quite helpful after struggling for about an hour, this solution worked for me. Thank you! :-)